# how to combine two lines in a files then sort it

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, please help, I have a text file with date:

```
id      period   value  date
=============================
SEC A   -0.07   19831117
SEC A   -0.07   19831215
SEC Q   0.07    0
SEC A   0.01    0
SEC Q   -0.17   0
SEC Q   0.01    0
SEC Q   0.66    0
SEC A   -0.52   19860417
SEC A   -0.52   19860619
SEC A   -0.52   19860717
SEC A   -0.52   19860814
SEC A   -0.52   19860918
SEC A   -0.52   19861016
SEC Q   -0.38   19860417
SEC A   -0.3    0
SEC Q   -0.01   19860619
SEC Q   -0.01   19860717
SEC Q   -0.01   19861016
SEC Q   -0.1    19861120
```

I wanted to combine two lines based on 2nd column (A/Q) grouped by date (4th column ), if field A and Q in column two has same date (column4) then combined the lines into one, otherwise just print data where date is not zero:

Output file will look like this:

```
id      date            Value (A)   Valaue(Q)
===========================================
SEC 19831117    -1.17   0
SEC 19831215    -1.17   0
SEC 19860116    -1.36   1.02
SEC 19860220    -1.36   1.02
SEC 19860320    -1.36   1.02
SEC 19860417    -1.52   -1.38
SEC 19860619    -1.52   -1.01
SEC 19860717    -1.52   -1.01
SEC 19861016    -1.52   -1.01
```

Comment: I added my $file = 'C:\data.txt';
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file'\n";
my %hash;
my $lines = <$data>;
foreach ($lines){

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to key on date, so you want to create a record on the date. Note that I stored everything in the record, and that makes it more expandable for additional purposes.

```
my %hash;

foreach ( <lines> ) { 
    # split on whitespace
    my ( $id, $key, $value, $date ) = split ' ';
    # check for existing record to append to
    my $rec 
          = $hash{ $date } 
        # if this record is not found, it is initialized
        //= { id   => $id
            , date => $date
              # the following statement means *map* each string in ('A', 'Q')
              # to the default of 0
            , ( map { $_ => 0 } qw<A Q> ) 
            }
        ;
    # in both cases we want to set the value
    $hash{ $key } = $value;
}

foreach ( sort keys %hash ) { 
    my $rec = $hash{ $_ };
    say "$rec->{id}\t$_\t$rec->{A}\t$rec->{Q}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two separate hashes, one for A and one for Q. The key of the hash can be the date, and the value is the value. Iterate through the input to generate the hashes.

Once you have both hashes, iterate through one of the hashes and try to find entries in the other hash with the same date. Put the relevant information into a hash of arrays, keyed by the date. Pseudocode (since I can't remember perl syntax exactly):

```
%hashA = () ; # a hash of scalars 
%hashQ = () ; # a hash of scalars
%hashAQ = () ; # a hash of arrays of size two, element 1 is A's value, element 2 is Q's value

## TODO: Put code to read the input and populate the first two hashes above 

foreach($key in hashA) {
    if (exists $hashQ{$key}) { 
        $hashAQ{$key} = @($hashA{key}, $hashQ{key}) ; 
    }
}  

## TODO: sort hashAQ by the key (which is the date) and then print the values
```

If there can be multiple values for A (or Q) with the same date, then have your hash use array values instead of scaler values. The arrays will contain all values of A (or Q) from the relevant date.